# Precompiler notion for project type (target) in VC#

Tags: c#, precompile

Just the same as if a project in DEBUG / RELEASE mode
We use

```
#ifdef DEBUG
...
```

Is there something the same for TARGET? (exe / lib / winexe) ?

Comment: If you look at the out of the box project configuration for the Debug configuration, you will see that DEBUG is on the list of pre-defined symbols. That's what puts it there. You can any symbols you want, EXE, DOG, whatever. There's no magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything built in, but in your build you can define *anything you like*; this could be done manually per-project, or you can do it more dynamically; here's an example that conditionally appends a `PLAT_NO_EMITDLL` symbol if the target framework is (either of a few), so that the code can `#if PLAT_NO_EMITDLL` rather than having all the "which framework has what platform features" logic in the C# files:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);PLAT_NO_EMITDLL</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.1'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);PLAT_NO_EMITDLL</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In your case, you might want to look at `$(OutputType)`.